# Clear git repository created in main directory

Tags: git, repository, git-bash

I created a repository in the main directory of my git bash, I can't seem to leave and create another repository or commit anything in other repositories. I am either trying to delete the repository created in the main directory or ignore it.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, all I had to do was go to the directory where I created my repository and throw in `rm -fr .git` . It deleted the repository that was bothering me and let me continue.